# I want to check if column value is today date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code.
In column there are values of 2020-07-06 11:59:34 and 2020-07-06 11:59:45.
I don't want to compare time but only date. I want to check if column value is today date.
But the output of this code is 0.

```
require_once "connect.php";

$followers = $conn->query("SELECT  *  FROM followers WHERE DATE('created_date') = CURDATE() and profile_id=1");

echo $followers->num_rows;
```

Comment: `'created_date'` is a string. Perhaps you were thinking of `created_date`. Also, note that functions cannot use indexes, so something like `created_date` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` is preferable

Comment: I don't understand. created_date is column name and its type is timestamp

Comment: Anything wrapped in inverted commas is a string, not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use single quotes  for columns name (eventually use backtics when needed)

```
SELECT  *  FROM followers WHERE DATE(created_date) = CURDATE() and profile_id=1
```

Comment: I wouldn't instigate legal proceedings against punctuation under any circumstances

Comment: @strawberry   ..   summons avoided  (it would seem)